# How to solve 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | S' (ts2345)

Tags: typescript, react-query

I am trying to implement generic mutation function using ReactQuery, the code works fine but I am getting a type error which I could not solve. Can someone help me to understand what exactly TS wants from me?

Type error:

```
Argument of type '(oldData: T | undefined) => T | S' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Updater<T | undefined, T>'.  Type '(oldData: T | undefined) => T | S' is not assignable to type 'DataUpdateFunction<T | undefined, T>'.
Type 'T | S' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | S'.ts(2345)
```

--

```
const useGenericMutation = <T, S>(
func: (data: S) => Promise<AxiosResponse<S>>,
url: string,
params?: object,
updater?: ((oldData: T, newData: S) => T) | undefined
) => {
 
const queryClient = useQueryClient();

return useMutation<AxiosResponse, AxiosError, S>(func, {
    onMutate: async (data) => {
        await queryClient.cancelQueries([url!, params]);

        const previousData = queryClient.getQueryData([url!, params]);

        queryClient.setQueryData<T>([url!, params], (oldData) => {
            return updater ? updater(oldData!, data) : data;
        });

        return previousData;
    },
    onError: (err, _, context) => {
        queryClient.setQueryData([url!, params], context);
    },
    onSettled: () => {
        queryClient.invalidateQueries([url!, params]);
    },
});};
```

On this line:

```
    queryClient.setQueryData<T>([url!, params], (oldData) => {
            return updater ? updater(oldData!, data) : data;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`T` and `S` have no relation. The problem is that the updater function from `setQueryData` returns `T | S`, but it should only return `T`:

```
queryClient.setQueryData<T>([url!, params], (oldData) => {
  return updater ? updater(oldData!, data) : data;
});
```

if `updater` is `undefined`, you just return `data`, which is of type `S`.

since you already get `previousData` with `getQueryData`, you can just not call `setQueryData` and also don't use the updater function:

```
const previousData = queryClient.getQueryData<T>([url!, params]);

if (updater && previousData) {
  queryClient.setQueryData<T>([url!, params], updater(previousData, data))
}
```

[Here is a TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwLACg5wK4GcCmBFDHKATwGEAbYHAOxgBpV1scBZDGAQxmAmtQF84AMygQQcAORQcHAMYwAtAEdCJCQG5UqUJFiI4AQQAePLACUcWSNVx1DJiFgCiUUVDiCRYyRwdYJWiiyvFjwzADiNETAsmyc3LxwALxwADwAKnYAygB8ABSMwhjUsgBccHkAJlwc5VkAlMk5cAAKoiDAuKnGphZWITipuTkMaJhQ5OWhUMDUAOaj6GAcUBwgWAD85RAARgBWOPKLmGDVMERbFXkQ5JUAIjXlmXDUOADuD5x1jUnN6Y0AH0w1EqOCEsxwlVQP2ayBQhWCNngKiIZEoNHgKWYBFRFCotDy9U08LG0hgGCg1EwuDiXB41G6fj61ls9lMLjc2XyQmKsjscPQ6F4tPO5Q4WGIJQqZw4MMQhUFcA4bw4wGRqjR%20JgADpZBwSjhyDiZpY8gBtCnkACEdmWq3WAF0iYFFehEaE4GBpAA3HjYT4cZJwFEkPEY7VzHAwY3EAMZfIWiY2z0rNZYJ3EhWC4BCCoYU5cIhwABkxc9Pr9WADjQFrvQIc14dw0Y1cfSCctybtaYddnzZyIeS9OF9EH9NTsMvq9Sz6H4LtdZIpVOHo-HnGJiv4xyF1A50HKeSIUDsAH07IjzkYYHLa4qG2HaNrmzGA%20bO7bU46L7wrzfN4K25ZrwWRRjA5CQoet6zsGGqPjqszehwlADsaVBYO%20Safva6bOmMc7HPweH8OoQA) with that solution.

---

In React Query v4, it will also be allowed to return *undefined* from the functional updater of `setQueryData`, which indicates that you'd like to bail out of the update. So in that case, if you have no updater, you can do:

```
queryClient.setQueryData<T>([url!, params], (oldData) => {
  return updater ? updater(oldData!, data) : undefined;
});
```

which should be equivalent to my solution calling `setQueryData` conditionally.

---

If your intention was to really just put `data` into the cache if there is no `updater` function passed in, then you need to convince the compiler that the data returned from `func` (which is of `type S`) is the same as the data expected in the query cache (which is of `type T`).

Defining `S` as: `<T, S extends T>` works, but it means you can't do arbitrary data transformations.